# why DerefMut is not implemented for `std::cell::RefMut<'_, [..]>` which wraps FnMut?

Tags: rust, closures, mutable

I want to wrap a `FnMut` closure in a `RefCell` like the following:

```rust
fn borrow_mut_closure() {
    let mut temp = 3i32;
    let cl = RefCell::new(move || {
        temp += 1;
        println!("{}", temp);
    });
    cl.borrow_mut()();
}
```

But to my surprise, the compiler reports:

```
cannot borrow data in a dereference of `std::cell::RefMut<'_, [closure@src/main.rs:17:25: 20:4 temp:i32]>` as mutable

cannot borrow as mutable

help: trait `DerefMut` is required to modify through a dereference, but it is not implemented for `std::cell::RefMut<'_, [closure@src/main.rs:17:25: 20:4 temp:i32]>`rustc(E0596)
```

But why not implemented for that? How could I overcome this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a compiler bug. It seems like it may be the same issue reported here: [Cannot borrow as mutable despite DerefMut](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/51886).

Your code will work if you change

```
cl.borrow_mut()();
```

to instead be

```
(&mut *cl.borrow_mut())();
```

to explicitly dereference the value as mutable before calling it.